# Windows 8 App for Metro IE (not for app store)

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-8

I am currently working on an app for a company to showcase their product range. This application is to be hosted and ran on their Windows Surface RT tablets. I am almost finished the development of the application and it all works great. I am using hammer.js and CSS3 for the development of the touch aspects of the application. I have been testing the application on a Windows Surface by uploading to a temporary server space.

My problem comes into play as the client would like the application to sit on the Surface device and be accessible without an internet connection. Another reason we do not want to push this over the internet is because the image files that we are using are going to be ver big! As this application is company specific they would not like it to be hosted on the Windows App Store. I have been looking into how i can wrap the files up as an app and deploy it onto the Surface tablet and the only thing that I can find is a product called PhoneGap (Cordova). However after some searching and playing around I cant seem to see how I can get this to work.

My other problem is that I need the application to open as a Metro app (i.e. have its own tab on the windows 8 interface). Another option would be to open it in the native metro IE application, however I am unsure if this is possible?

If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some links to look at that would be great.

Please ask if you would like anymore information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a bit more research!

Cordova does support Windows 8 Store Apps:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html

And there is an enterprise deployment model for Windows 8 Store Apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx

Follow these guides, and if you get stuck come back an ask some more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you for the links this has helped. I have read over them and this gives me a bit more insight into what is possible. Do you know if the enterprise deployment model is free? Also how do I go about creating a package to deploy to the Surface tablet?